# Swift: change UIImageView image midway during animation

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, core-animation

I have this code to create animation `imageView`:

```
        imageView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0.5)

        var transform = CATransform3DIdentity
        transform.m34 = -0.001
        imageView.layer.transform = transform
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 3) {
            self.imageView.layer.transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, .pi, 0, 1, 0)

            self.imageViewCenterConstraintX.constant = 0

            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
```

In this code `imageView` rotate with 180 degrees. I want to change image after `imageView` rotate with 90 degrees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should chain the two animations, each rotating with pi/2.

```
imageView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0.5)

var transform = CATransform3DIdentity
transform.m34 = -0.001
imageView.layer.transform = transform
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: 
{
   self.imageView.layer.transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, .pi/2, 0, 1, 0)
   self.imageViewCenterConstraintX.constant = 0  
 }) 
     { 
         (bCompleted) in
         if (bCompleted)
         {
            self.imageView?.layer.transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, .pi/2, 0, 1, 0)
         }

         UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: 
         {
              self.imageView.layer.transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, .pi*0.999, 0, 1, 0)
              self.imageView.image = UIImage.init(named:"anotherImage")
         }, 
         completion: 
         { 
            (bFinished) in
            //Whatever
         })
  }
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174125/discussion-between-nirav-bhatt-and-111).

Answer (score 0):

You could use `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter`.

```
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 3) {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.5) {
            // Change your image here
        }
        self.imageView.layer.transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, .pi, 0, 1, 0)

        self.imageViewCenterConstraintX.constant = 0

        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
```

Comment: In this case my image not always change on 90 degrees. Sometimes image change after 90 degrees.